# Java GUI application for selecting players

Tags: java

I have automated a small task. My application is a windows based application. I was using Java language and worked with Winium tool. I have to select players from the GUI and there is a scroll up and down is in another place. I want to improve my coding. There is some repetition in my code. How do i avoid that ?

```
public class LineUps {

    private WiniumDriver driver;
    public LineUps(WiniumDriver driver) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void away_team_lineups_excel() {
        try {
            driver.findElementById("lblAwayTeamHittersAll").click();
            WebElement away_players_list1 = driver.findElementById("lsvAwayTeamHitters1");
            WebElement away_players_list2 = driver.findElement(By.id("lsvAwayTeamHitters2"));

            List < WebElement > away_team_players_lineups1 = away_players_list1.findElements(By.xpath("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'item')]"));
            List < WebElement > away_team_players_lineups2 = away_players_list2.findElements(By.xpath("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'item')]"));

            List < String > away_players1 = new ArrayList < String > ();
            for (int i = 0; i < away_team_players_lineups1.size(); i++) {
                List < WebElement > away_team_players_names = away_team_players_lineups1.get(i).findElements(By.xpath("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'text')]"));

                for (int j = 3; j < away_team_players_names.size(); j++) {
                    String celtext = away_team_players_names.get(j).getAttribute("Name");

                    away_players1.add(celtext);

                }
            }

            List < String > away_players2 = new ArrayList < String > ();
            for (int j = 0; j < away_team_players_lineups2.size(); j++) {
                List < WebElement > away_team_players_names2 = away_team_players_lineups2.get(j).findElements(By.xpath("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'text')]"));

                for (int k = 3; k < away_team_players_names2.size(); k++) {
                    String celtext = away_team_players_names2.get(k).getAttribute("Name");

                    away_players2.add(celtext);
                }
            }
            away_players2.addAll(away_players1);
            List < String > away_players3 = new ArrayList < String > ();
            away_players3.addAll(away_players2);


            File f = new File("Player_names.xlsx");
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
            XSSFSheet bb_players = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
            int rowcount = bb_players.getLastRowNum();


            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            for (int i = 1; i <= rowcount; i++) {
                String player = bb_players.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                String position = bb_players.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();


                for (int j = 0; j < away_players3.size(); j++) {
                    String away_total_players = away_players3.get(j);

                    if (away_total_players.equals(player)) {
                        boolean exist = driver.findElementByName(player).isDisplayed();

                        if (exist) {
                            WebElement line_up1 = driver.findElementByName(player);

                            action.moveToElement(line_up1).doubleClick().build().perform();
                            List < String > away_plyers_positions = new ArrayList < String > ();

                            WebElement away_players_pos = driver.findElementById("PlayerPositions");

                            List < WebElement > player_pos = away_players_pos.findElements(By.xpath("./*[contains(@ControlType,'Button')]"));

                            for (int a = 0; a < player_pos.size(); a++) {
                                away_plyers_positions.add(player_pos.get(a).getAttribute("Name"));
                                String aw_player_pos = away_plyers_positions.get(a);

                                if (position.equals(aw_player_pos)) {
                                    player_pos.get(a).click();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (!exist) {
                            WebElement scroll = away_players_list2.findElement(By.name("Forward by large amount"));
                            scroll.click();
                            WebElement line_up2 = driver.findElementByName(player);

                            action.moveToElement(line_up2).doubleClick().build().perform();


                            List < String > away_plyers_positions = new ArrayList < String > ();

                            WebElement away_players_pos = driver.findElementById("PlayerPositions");

                            List < WebElement > player_pos = away_players_pos.findElements(By.xpath("./*[contains(@ControlType,'Button')]"));

                            for (int a = 0; a < player_pos.size(); a++) {
                                away_plyers_positions.add(player_pos.get(a).getAttribute("Name"));
                                String aw_player_pos = away_plyers_positions.get(a);

                                if (position.equals(aw_player_pos)) {
                                    player_pos.get(a).click();
                                }
                            }
                            WebElement scroll1 = away_players_list2.findElement(By.name("Back by large amount"));

                            scroll1.click();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

My code is getting the player names from the tables and check whether the player is in the view, then it selects the player and meanwhile selects his position. If he's not in view, it scrolls down and selects the player and his position, and then scrolls up again…

Comment: As a side node, please stick to the java naming conventions (see: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Instead for every player/team data structures, make a `List<Player resp. Team>`. Then you can loop over the two players, and then loop over the corresponding names and such.

Comment: @ Joop Eggen   yes I put the respective player in excel sheet.. I do looping through excel take one player ...and check whether match or not....